# Since offline_access is deprecated, how will we publish content on pages via server?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-oauth

I want to be more specific on the question in detail...

I have an app, a page and a webserver. Webserver sends any newly publish content via my user to mypage as link / picture etc. Because I use offline_access token and stuff.

I know old accesses will continue but imagine it as new user. Problem starts with deprecation of offline_access ability of apps. Now my server will not be able to publish because it will not have access_token of me "server-side" permenantly. I will have to give access everytime server tries to send something. So I will not automate it...

Is there any other way to do this without offline_access? I mean can my app have direct access to my fanpage to send without user (in this case myself) authorization?

I have to repeat, I don't use offline_access in any other way about posting other users stream or pages. I just request it to post it to my fanpage (which I also administrate)

Comment: Please see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation/

Answer (score 1):

When not useing offline_access token does not mean that you can't not use the token to publish on an different server, just that the token will expire at some time.

But as I understand you I think you can use publish_stream see more at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/